# Increase variable value of Balance<T> type

Tags: pallet

I am developing a Pallet and I defined this type:

```
type BalanceOf<T> =
        <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;
```

and my question is how to add value of this `tmp` value with input amount:

```
let mut tmp:BalanceOf<T>;
pub fn mint(
            owner: &T::AccountId,
            amount: BalanceOf<T>,
        ) -> Result<[u8; 3], DispatchError> {
   // How to increase tmp value with input amount
}
```

my Cargo.toml of pallet:
and it caused: `Caused by: Dependency 'sp-runtime' has different source paths depending on the build target. Each dependency must have a single canonical source path irrespective of build target.`

```
[package]
name = 'pallet-nft-wcn'
version = '4.0.0-dev'
description = 'FRAME pallet template for defining custom runtime logic.'
authors = ['Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>']
homepage = 'https://substrate.io/'
edition = '2021'
license = 'Unlicense'
publish = false
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "2.0.0", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive",
] }
scale-info = { version = "1.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
frame-support = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17"}
frame-system = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17" }
frame-benchmarking = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17", optional = true }
sp-runtime = { version = "5.0.0"}
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
sp-std = { default-features = false, version = '3.0.0' }


[dev-dependencies]
sp-core = { default-features = false, version = "5.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17" }
sp-io = { default-features = false, version = "5.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17" }
sp-runtime = { default-features = false, version = "5.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "codec/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "frame-benchmarking/std",
]

runtime-benchmarks = ["frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks"]
try-runtime = ["frame-support/try-runtime"]
```

Comment: In rust, variables are generally defined inside functions unless they are statics or constants.

Comment: @Squirrel yes, it's consider as global variable `#[pallet::storage]`

Comment: My apologies - I did not know that that was possible. Those sneaky macros!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to provide more clarity what is failing for you, but this works fine:

```rust
fn add_balance(balance1: BalanceOf<T>, balance2: BalanceOf<T>) -> BalanceOf<T> {
    use sp_runtime::traits::Saturating;
    balance1.saturating_add(balance2)
}
```

Comment: I have to declared `sp_runtime` in `dependencies` in Cargo.toml, but I encounter this error: `Dependency 'sp-runtime' has different source paths depending on the build target. Each dependency must have a single canonical source path irrespective of build target.`

Comment: You need to share your TOML file. Maybe you want to ask a new question and we can help you there.

Comment: I'm using the latest substrate-node-template, and please see my updated question

Comment: please take a look at my answer, I have updated.

Comment: Sorry Rong, but you didnt even spend a second to think about how you imported this crate, and to compare it to any other crate in that file and how it is being imported. Please follow patterns outlined by the other imports of substrate crates.

Comment: If you still don't understand, please open a new question with specifically asking how to properly import a crate into an existing substrate project

Comment: I tried another lib(`use sp_arithmetic::traits::Saturating`,..), but I have same error `method cannot be called on '<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance' due to unsatisfied trait bounds`. Sorry Shawn, I'm new to Substrate :)

Comment: I found another solution, thank you for your support.

Answer (score 7):

There is a `Saturating` math trait in the arithmetic primitives - you can use that:

```
use sp_arithmetic::traits::Saturating;
tmp.saturating_accrue(amount);
```

You can also use `AddAssign` or `CheckedAdd` traits if you either don't care about overflow(!) or want to handle it other than by saturating.

Comment: I encounted this error: `error[E0599]: the method 'saturating_accrue' exists for associated type '<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance', but its trait bounds were not satisfied`. Thank for your answer!

Comment: I defined `BalanceOf<T>` as `Type`, So I cannot implement trait for it